# Find $v \in H^1(0,1)$ which satisfies the following

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Determine the function $v \in H^1(0,1)$ which satisfies the equation $u(0)=\langle u,v \rangle_{H^1}$ for all $u\in H^1(0,1)$ .

It is clear that on $H^1(0,1)$; $u(0)=\int_{0}^{1}(uv+u'v')$.What can be  the function $v$ satisfying the above equation? Please help?

Comment: Hint: Let $w=u-u(0)$ What is $\int w v +w'v'$ equal to ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we assume that $v$ is twice-differentiable, we can integrate the $u'v'$ term by parts, so the equation becomes
$$ u(0) = u(1)v'(1)-u(0)v'(0) + \int_0^1 (-v''(x)+v(x))u(x) \, dx. $$
Therefore a natural thing to do now is find a function that satisfies $v'(0)=-1$, $v'(1)=0$, and $-v''+v=0$ in between. Some elementary differential equation solving later, we find that the unique choice for $v$ that satisfies these is
$$ v(x) = \frac{e^x+e^{2-x}}{e^2-1}, $$
and so this is the only possible twice-differentiable $v$.

Comment: A minor remark: there is some assumption of additional regularity than you have *a priori* in making this manipulation. It can be justified *a posteriori*.

Comment: @Ian Fair point. I've edited to clarify.

Comment: @Chappers... Thanks for you clear solution. But how come the result be $v(x) = \frac{e^x+e^{2-x}}{e^2-1}$? When I use  Euler–Lagrange equation technique, it yields $v=v''$. Still confused.

Comment: @A.Get This $v$ does satisfy $v''=v$.

Comment: @ Chappers.. What is the technique to get this $v$?. Thanks.

Comment: Using auxiliary equation for $v''-v=0$, I got $v(x)=e^x+c$.

Comment: @A.Get No, sticking $v=e^{kx}$ in gives $k^2-1=0$, so the general solution is $Ae^{x}+Be^{-x}$.

Comment: Ohh I see my mistake.. Thank you so much!